# Can't use {{#for}} helper on empty hasMany relationships

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Here is a model I'm trying to render right now:

```
App.Teacher = DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true}),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    students: DS.hasMany('student', {async: true})
});
```

and here's the template attempting to display it:

```
{{#with teacher}}

    {{description}}

    {{#for student in students}}
        {{student.full_name}}
    {{/for}}

{{/with}}
```

Initially this model is empty:

```
var teacher = this.get('store').createRecord('teacher', {
    description: description,
    user: model,
    students: []
});
```

since this user just barely signed up to be a teacher.
Whenever I click the button to sign up a teacher, the controller creates the empty model and saves everything, and when I only had the `description` and `user` fields, it worked just fine. Since adding the `hasMany`s and the `{{for}}`s though, I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error:  Handlebars error: Could not find property 'for' on object <DS.PromiseObject:ember488>
```

Any thoughts?

Also, I'm using couchdb, and when the teacher model is saved, the empty arrays don't end up in the persisted record, both when I provide empty arrays to `createRecord` *and* when I don't. Is that a problem? I'm using [this couchdb adapter](https://github.com/roundscope/ember-couchdb-kit).

Comment: `#for` is rendered as a property of `teacher`? Is `#with` good Ember practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you tryin to use `#each`? `#for` isn't a real thing.

http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/

Comment: LOL "not a real thing"

Comment: I just had surgery and am flying high on oxycodone, and my dominant hand is slung up, so short responses are easier to peck left handed, no offense blaineh ;)

Comment: I'm literally deleting this question, it's too embarrassing.